# how to find out what takes a lot of disk space?

Tags: hard-drive, lubuntu

I am working on Lubuntu. Recently I noticed that my disk space is shrinking badly even though it was quite ok at the begin. I remove all tmp, unused apps, downloads and it still gave me almost nothing. Is there a tool (preferably graphical but not necessary) to get some kind of report of directory sizes (even better: recursively so I can run a test and then check subdirs to find the "guilty one")?

Comment: I'd suggest `du -h -t 1G | sort -h` because it'll only list directories bigger than 1GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can try this: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/baobab/ :)

It shows you all folders in system and they size.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using the command `du` you may want to use the `-h` flag so its human readable. So thusly I recommend:

```
du -h
```

This will give you a very long list of sizes and paths.

Good luck!

Comment: +1 I use this version that shows the largest files last: `du -hs * | sort -h`

Comment: I'd suggest `du -h -t 1G | sort -h` because it'll only list directories bigger than 1GB.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't worry, there is a quick and safe solution**, just follow this mini-guide.

Open a bash terminal (`CTRL`+`ALT`+`t`), copy-paste the following command inside it and press `ENTER`:

```
du --human-readable --max-depth 5 --one-file-system ~ | grep ^[0-9\,\.]*[M\|G\|T].*$ | zenity --list --title="Huge files" --column=Files --text= --editable&
```

This is a simple script that shows a window with a list of all big files: click on an entry to select and copy the file path, find the file and then delete it.
**The script does NOT delete the files**, do it manually after checking if you need to do a backup and remember to empty the trash.

[image: Screen-shot for the one-line file listing script]

<sup>NOTE: I've made the script 5 minutes ago and is very "spartan", please report any bug in the comments, thank you. ;-)</sup>
<sup>NOTE: execute `sudo apt-get install zenity` if you get a "missing command" error.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help you.

**In Terminal**
df -h

See more at:
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-analyze-your-disk-usage-pattern-in-linux/

Comment: Not really because I get just `/dev/sda1` as for my drive without info what exactly takes most space...